# python codes works with mysql,'drop table ' takes too long

Tags: python, mysql

I make a test on travis-ci.org .

the test code is

```
import MySQLdb

create_tbl_SQL = open("tables.sql").read()

conn = MySQLdb.connect(db = "test_travis", user = "root", passwd = "", charset =     "utf8", host = "localhost", port = 3306)

def create_tables():
    conn.cursor().execute(create_tbl_SQL)

def drop_tables():
    conn.cursor().execute("drop table user, post;")

create_tables()

conn1 = MySQLdb.connect(db = "test_travis", user = "root", passwd = "", charset =    "utf8", host = "localhost", port = 3306)

c = conn1.cursor()

c.execute("insert into user set user.name = '111'")

c.execute("select * from user; ")

drop_tables()
```

but the tests on travis-ci.org takes 3 min to run this.

this code is on github:https://github.com/hit9/test_mysql_on_travis/

this test on travis-ci.org:https://travis-ci.org/hit9/test_mysql_on_travis

I think the 'drop table' action makes this script running slow.

but how can i solve this ?

Comment: What makes you think that? Have you tried without the drop table statement?

Comment: Thinking means not knowing...what is your evidence for your claim?

Comment: yes.I have tried codes without the drop statement. I replace drop with "select * from user". And then  codes run far more faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried

```
mysql -e "set autocommit=1"
```

in my .travis.yml,but that was not working

So,I should insert this line before the drop statement

```
c.execute("commit ")
```

Comment: conn.autocommit(1) is better

Comment: the stackoverflow will warn me : You can accept your own answer in 21 hours